# How to fix a corrupt java file (link?) in Eclipse (maven, svn)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn

The project is a maven project and stored in SVN.
Suddenly when I was editing the java file an error message showed up: An error has occurred. Se errorlog for more details. offset 71980, count -47813, length 97754.

When i left-click on the java file in the Package explorer window I get this error message immediately. When right-click on this file and open it, the java-file above (in the package explorer) opends.

I can not delete the file: An unexpected exception occured while performing the refactoring. se error log for more details. offset 71980, count -47813, length 97754.

I can not not run Maven update project: Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'jdbcconnection'.
offset 71980, count -47813, length 97754.

I can not update the file from SVN since the "Team" option is gone for this java file.

Log file:

```
    !SESSION 2022-05-17 10:51:04.056 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.17.0.I20200902-1800
java.version=14.0.2
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=sv_SE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
This is a continuation of log file C:\Program Files\nyDatorWorkspace\.metadata\.bak_6.log
Created Time: 2022-05-17 13:50:33.749
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2022-05-17 13:50:33.750
!MESSAGE An exception occurred while notifying part listeners
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.eclipse.ui.internal.ErrorEditorPart cannot be cast to class org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DesignerEditor (org.eclipse.ui.internal.ErrorEditorPart is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @4087c7fc; org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DesignerEditor is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @45382749)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DesignerEditorContributor.setActiveEditor(DesignerEditorContributor.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorActionBars.partChanged(EditorActionBars.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.updateActivations(WorkbenchPage.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$2(WorkbenchPage.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$E4PartListener.partActivated(WorkbenchPage.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$2.run(PartServiceImpl.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.firePartActivated(PartServiceImpl.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.AbstractPartRenderer.activate(AbstractPartRenderer.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.lambda$0(ContributedPartRenderer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4195)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setActiveControl(Shell.java:1469)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setActiveControl(Shell.java:1432)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.sendFocusEvent(Control.java:2974)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmSetFocus(Widget.java:2266)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_SETFOCUS(Control.java:5440)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4831)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.windowProc(Text.java:2681)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4913)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SetFocus(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.forceFocus(Control.java:1111)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setFocus(Control.java:3459)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1072)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ErrorEditorPart.setFocus(ErrorEditorPart.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.delegateSetFocus(CompatibilityPart.java:222)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor56.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.focusGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer$1.setFocus(ContributedPartRenderer.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabItem.setFocus(CTabItem.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setFocus(CTabFolder.java:2676)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.fixFocus(Control.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setVisible(Control.java:3970)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3229)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3186)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1221)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.lambda$0(LazyStackRenderer.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.lambda$0(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4725)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElementGen(ElementContainerImpl.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.hidePart(PartServiceImpl.java:1378)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.hidePart(PartServiceImpl.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.closePart(StackRenderer.java:1182)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.access$0(StackRenderer.java:1168)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer$3.close(StackRenderer.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1958)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.lambda$0(CTabFolder.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4195)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4012)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3612)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1157)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please show your log starting with `!SESSION`.

Comment: The log is starting with !SESSION and are 11000 rows! Is it something special you want to see?

Comment: Possibly [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=567319) which was fixed in Eclipse 4.18 (2020-12)

Comment: Starting with the last (not first) `!SESSION`.

Comment: Sorry Howgler, but the first !SESSION is the only one in the log-file

Comment: Greg-449, are you meaning that if I upgrade to Eclipse 4.18, my workspace will be fixed. I don't understand the discussion in the link you provided.

Comment: Howlger, the log have changed and is smaller. I've updated the log in the question.

Comment: All I can say is that the original error you reported has been fixed. You should try running the current Eclipse (2022-03)

Comment: The log confirms what greg-449 says: the bug existed only in 4.17 and according to the log it is the version you have. Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17) is 6 releases behind. Please upgrade.